# How do I copy a PDF into my internal storage? -Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I would like to copy the pdf from the download folder into my app (internal storage). Problem is that the method throws a `NullPointerExeption`.

```
    File source = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Download/test1.pdf");
    File dest = new File("/data/user/0/com.example.meinuniverwalter/files/Gson");

 try{

     copyFileUsingStream(source,dest);


     }catch(IOException e){
     e.printStackTrace();
     }

    private static void copyFileUsingStream(File source, File dest) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = null;
    OutputStream os = null;
    try {
        is = new FileInputStream(source);
        os = new FileOutputStream(dest);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            os.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
    } finally {
        is.close();
        os.close();
    }
}
```

This is my Logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.meinuniverwalter, PID: 28195
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.meinuniverwalter/com.example.meinuniverwalter.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.io.InputStream.close()' on a null object reference
```

Comment: `"/data/user/0/com.example.meinuniverwalter/files/Gson"` That looks like a folder path. Dont you want the file to keep its name? Like `"/data/user/0/com.example.meinuniverwalter/files/Gson/test1.pdf"` ?

Comment: You should check if the source exists with source.exists() and the destination if it is a directory dest.isDirectory(). And atdd a catch(){} block. For the rest it is irrelevant that it is a pdf file. You can copy any file with that code.

Comment: `the method throws a NullPointerExeption.` The Logcat tells you exactly which line and which statement causes that. You should post the logcat and tell us which line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has something to do with your finally block. In order to get more info why this happens you can add a 'catch' block with that 'try'.

You could also add a null check with the 'is' in your finally block.
Resulting in a method like:

```
private static void copyFileUsingStream(File source, File dest) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = null;
    OutputStream os = null;

    try {
        is = new FileInputStream(source);
        os = new FileOutputStream(dest);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            os.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (is != null){
            is.close();
        }
        if (os != null){
            os.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Do know that in order to work with files and such, you need to ask the user for permissions. No idea if you already incorporated this in your application, but due to the lack of information I add some links for more information.

See [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview) for more information about asking permissions from the android developers portal.

See [this](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files/internal) for more information about working with files, also from the android developers portal.

Answer (score 0):

The NullPointerException is coming from your finally block. To get more information of the error try catching the error and log it. For me, it seems like file not found, therefore the InputStream is null. You can access the download directory like:

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
```

And to access individual files in this directory use either File.list() or File.listFiles().
Also, make sure you have the right permissions in you Manifest file.